# How to define a d3 data path and data field separator

Tags: d3.js

I'm using **d3.js** to include some comma separated data in a HTML page. Two problems I (a bloody beginner) am not able to solve:

- To use a pipe `|` as a separator/delimiter in the data file (plain text) instead of comma.
- To link d3 to use the data from a subfolder data.

The call of d3 is located in an index.htm to a subfolder syst where d3.js is - this works.

Moving the data.csv to the subfolder data the file will not be found although I tried to define the path with `data/data.csv` and `/data/data.csv`

Sinve I need commas in my data set I want to replace this default delimiter with a pipe`|`. Changing the code below to`d3.dsv("|", "data.dsv" ..` doesn't work.

```
<div id="datatable"></div>
<script>
var rows = []
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, csv) {
    csv.forEach(function(row) {
    rows.push(row);
});

    var table = d3.select("#datatable").append("table");
      thead = table.append("thead");
      tbody = table.append("tbody");

    var tr = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(rows)
        .enter().append("tr");

    var td = tr.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d) { return [d.media, d.info]; })
        .enter().append("td")
        .html(function(d) { return d; });
});
</script>
```

The result of my attempts are 1. to find no data, 2. the script will be ignored.

Comment: If you need commas in your CSV, just enclose the values between quotes(`"`). No need to mess with DSVs.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo for the answer. d3.js was choosen because the documentation says that it can handle other delimiters as (semi-)colon, pipes. To add quotes to every data field makes the editing of the data file quite confusing.

Comment: Many thanks to you, amirali, for re-formatting my first post here. I see, I have to become more familiar with this forum software, not only with d3.js ;-)